# 「基本設定」ページで一部チェックボックスの補足情報が英語のままになっている

Tags: バグ, 完了, 翻訳, 英語

### 不具合事象

「[基本設定](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/users/preferences/)」ページの一部チェックボックスで、設定されている補足情報 (`title` 属性の値) が英語のままになっています。

[image: チェックボックスにホバーすると、 Hide Hot Network Questions という翻訳されていない英文が表示される]

[image: チェックボックスにホバーすると、 Use On-Site Activity for Relevant Content という翻訳されていない英文が表示される]

---

### 翻訳案

1. **原文**

   > Hide Hot Network Questions

   **翻訳案**

   > ネットワークで話題の質問を表示しない
2. **原文**

   > Use On-Site Activity for Relevant Content

   **翻訳案**

   > 関連したコンテンツを表示するために、サイト上でのアクティビティを使う

Comment: `Hide Hot Network Questions` は最近訳出したので、まだサイトに変更が反映されてないだけかもしれません。

Comment: @nekketsuuu 翻訳済みのテキストはスクリーンショットでも反映されていますが(チェックボックス脇の文字列)、今回問題なのは恐らく「ツールチップで表示される文字列」で、元となるstringが確かに見つかりません。 / 「Hide Hot Network Questions」で検索すれば2つ出てくるはずが、1つしかないですよね？

Comment: @cubick あっ本当ですね勘違いしていました、ありがとうございます。どちらのチェックボックスにも title の string が翻訳対象になってないバグがあるという訳ですね。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

現在、該当箇所でツールチップは出現しなくなっています。HTML上も `title` 属性が無くなっています。デザイン変更に伴なって削除されたものと思われます。

Comment: 他もそうですが、「知らない間に直ってた」は「再現性なし」タグもあります。

Comment: @cubick 確かに、これらのバグに対する個別的対応は無かったのだろうと思いますし、「完了」には私も違和感が有ります。
ただ、Stack Exchange社の能動的な行動（このケースではデザイン変更）に伴う解決であることはほぼ確実なので、「完了」を選択しています。
他の方が「再現性なし」を付けても反対はしないです。